# How do you express duration in English?

Tags: time

Is this sentence correct?

> I can't breathe properly about 3 days.

Comment: The sentence you've given us doesn't make any sense. What do you want it to mean?

Comment: I mean i can't breathe properly now and it started 3 days ago

Comment: 'For'. Use the preposition 'for' when you talk about duration ('for a while', 'for a couple of hours', 'for three days', 'for about three days', etc.)

Answer (score 1):

**No**. I guess you're trying to say "**I haven't been able to breathe properly for three days.**"

Comment: Since Mary says it continues to the present, I would use a perfect form: _I haven't been able to breathe for three days_.

Comment: Just updated it.

Comment: Yeah this one is correct

Comment: Sounds like the OP hasn't been able to breathe entirely for 3 days. The OP might have some lung issue or something and your sentence is lacking the word "properly". The OP would've been dead.

Answer (score 1):

"I haven't been able to breathe properly for about three days."

More native then that would be:

"I haven't been able to breathe well for about three days now."

or

"I've been having trouble breathing for almost three days!"

"About" can mean "approximately".

"Now" is randomly inserted at the end of sentences which have previously mentioned times, sometimes.  It doesn't have any meaning.

If you instead meant to figure out whether or not "about" is the right word to describe a time frame: Is isn't.  "About" can mean "approximately," but if you weren't trying to say "approximately" thrn about is very, very incorrect.

You might say:

"I haven't been able to breathe properly FOR three days."  (Note that the word "for" is also included in my prior examples.)

"I haven't been able to breathe properly SINCE Wednesday."  (In this case, you have to say the specific name of a day, such as Wednesday, or you can say a date, such as November 25th.  You can also say a specific time like 3pm, a specific month or a specific year.)

"I haven't been able to breathe properly SINCE five hours AGO."  (This sentence works when using hours or minutes, but it is not okay to say when using days.  In some sentences, saying "since five hours ago" will sound strange.  In other sentences, it would be one normal way to say this.  In both cases, it is still a correct way.)

"I haven't been able to breathe properly STARTING three days AGO."

"I haven't been able to breathe properly EVER SINCE some other event occured."
"I haven't been able to breathe properly EVER SINCE I ate that tuna casserole." 
("Ever" does not mean anything in this sentence.  It is merely part of the term "ever since" and it does not have any independent meaning.)

"I haven't been able to breathe properly FOR THE LAST five hours.  (This can be used with hours, days, minites, years, or any other amount of time.  However, in the context of breathing, it makes the most sense to use this term with hours or minutes, because breathinv trouble is an immediate-issue, and is not normally a days-long issue.)

Answer (score 0):

> I can't breathe properly about 3 days.

This statement is (aside from other syntactical errors) in the present tense, so it doesn't make sense to put a time frame on it.

You would say:

> I haven't been able to breathe properly for about three days.